# How to sort keys in MAP while grouping

Tags: apex, map, list, sort

I am trying to insert list of wrapper class records in a MAP taking group name  as  KEY and related Wrapper class records as value pair .

the wrapper classes were

```
public class SCQLWrapperClass
{
   public date stDate{get;set;}
   public date endDate{get;set;}

   public String stDate1{get;set;}
   public String endDate1{get;set;}

    public double months{get;set;}
    public double quantty{get;set;}
    public double ppMonth{get;set;}
    public double discount{get;set;}
    public double netPrice{get;set;}        
    public double billTotal{get;set;}
    public String itmDesc{get;set;}        

}

public class groupingWrapClass
{
    public String yearname{get;set;}
    public Double billingtotal{get;set;}
    public Double pricepermonth{get;set;}
    public Double netpricepermonth{get;set;}        
    public List<SCQLWrapperClass> grpClsLst{get;set;}

    public groupingWrapClass(String yearname,Double pricepermonth,Double netpricepermonth,List<SCQLWrapperClass> grpClsLst)
    {
       this.yearname = yearname;
       this.pricepermonth = pricepermonth;
       this.netpricepermonth = netpricepermonth;
       this.grpClsLst = grpClsLst; 
    }

}
```

The Map was

Map map_lineitems_Group=new Map();

i was inserting values into the map taking keys from a sorted list as per user case.

the list contains group names { XYZ, ABC}

What ever the way i insert

```
map_lineitems_Group.put('XYZ', keyvalues);
map_lineitems_Group.put('ABC', keyvalues);
```

or in reverse way

```
map_lineitems_Group.put('ABC', keyvalues);
map_lineitems_Group.put('XYZ', keyvalues);
```

while iterating in VF page and debug logs too it is giving ABC as 1st group and XYZ as 2nd group. But i want it to be same order as in list.  This list is a dynamic list, so i cannot predict the order too..

I have tried to loop over the map with a duplicate map , but results the same ...

Is there any way to get the resulting map as desired...

Answer (score 6):

Java has multiple map classes such as [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) that preserve insertion order but Apex only has one map type which does not. So in Apex a work-around is to keep a separate list of the keys as lists preserve insertion order and get the keys to iterate through from the list:

```
private Map<string, groupingWrapClass> map_lineitems_Group
        = new Map<string, groupingWrapClass>();
private List<String> ordered_keys = new List<String>();

private void addToMap(String key, groupingWrapClass grouping) {
    map_lineitems_Group.put(key, grouping);
    ordered_keys.add(key);
}

private void xyz() {
    ...
    addToMap('XYZ', keyvalues);
    addToMap('ABC', keyvalues);
    ...
    // Run through the map keys in insertion order
    for (String key : ordered_keys) {
        groupingWrapClass grouping = map_lineitems_Group.get(key);
        ...
    }
}
```

**PS**

On exposing this to Visualforce, make both `ordered_keys` and `map_lineitems_Group` visible (add getters or make [properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)) and then e.g.:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ordered_keys}" var="ordered_key">
<apex:column headerValue="Year Name" value="{!map_lineitems_Group[ordered_key].yearname}"/>
...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

as expressions in Visualforce use `[]` for map access.

You could also add an [apex:variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm) to factor out the common `map_lineitems_Group[ordered_key]` expression.

Comment: thank's  keith, this was really good, i can iterate over it in insertion order as per list, but i want to project the same map to VF pages, so is there any way to iterate over the same in VF page

Comment: @rajasekhar See the PS.